# Extracting points as KML/KMZ from web map

Tags: qgis, point, kml, mapping, extract

This is the link: https://www.hopenvios.com.ar/. I would like to have the map with all points, does anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I would recommend taking a look this page on [how to ask a good question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Yes, it's possible, but your question is very open. Try to focus on a specific part of the problem you are struggling with, and let other users know what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the website with the inspector of your browser (F12 in Chrome and Firefox, or go through Settings to find it), you will see that the data is sourced from a public API.

I don't know what platform you want to use, but I have reconstructed the query using Python and arranged the request response into a [Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import datetime
import time

MAP_DATA_PICKUP = 'pickup'
DATE_TIME = str(int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())))

## query the API 
response = requests.get("https://www.hopenvios.com.ar/api/pickup_points.php?type=" + MAP_DATA_PICKUP + "&t=" + DATE_TIME)

## extract data from the response
data = response.json()['data']['pickupPoints']

## make dataframe from extracted data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

## look at first row
df.iloc(0)

## returns
name                                                  Gire S.A 367
lat                                                      -34.61070
lng                                                      -58.56069
fullAddress                                                       
zipCode                                                       1678
referenceName                                         Rapipago 367
schedules        [{'id': '0722b302-ef76-46fd-a098-42ecc79dad01'...
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

That should get you started, but if you need help with the next stage, you should ask a separate, more specific question.

Comment: How did you understand which parameters you will need for the `requests.get(..., params=params)`?

Comment: I just took another look and the params argument is not even needed. What I thought it was in the JavaScript is actually just an object into which the response data are sorted. I have updated my answer :)